# How to update on Two Tables

Tags: sql, windows

I need to make an update in a table based on other information.
How to proceed?
My case is:

I have a column iniciantes table `MEMB_INFO`
I need to make an **update** `MEMB_INFO SET iniciantes = 0`
But I need to make a query on `WHERE` table column resets the character table

Example:

```
UPDATE    MEMB_INFO
SET              iniciantes = 0
FROM         MEMB_INFO CROSS JOIN
                      Character
WHERE     (Character.Resets >= 100)
```

necessary that the update the memb_info only occur in cases where the reference character is greater than or equal to 100

Answer (score 1):

Simply, join MEMB_INFO with your `Character` table and specify their relations:

```
update m
set iniciantes = 0
from MEMB_INFO m
    inner join Character c on
    c.Resets >= 100 
    AND m.CharacterId = c.CharacterId  --Specify your tables' relations.
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify columns on which you're joining this two tables. If you have `characterId`  column in both tables, your query will be:

```
update MEMB_INFO set
    iniciantes = 0
from MEMB_INFO as m
where
    m.CharacterId in (
        select c.CharacterId from Character as c where c.Reset >= 100
    )
```